# Remove square brackets when writing to html file?

Tags: python, html, tkinter

I've tried `.replace` also tried `re.sub` and many other suggestions online, but I can't seem to remove these things. This is for assessment so I can't use any non-standard python libraries.

```
var = []

for itm in range(10):
  doSomething

  def itemList(itm):
    global var

    list = [list1[itm], list2[itm], list3[itm]] 

    var.append(list)

def writeToHtml():
    htmlFile.write('<li>' + ' <br></br>'.join(map(str, var)) + '</li>')

#this is what is written in html file
>>> ['stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff']

# But I need it to be
stuff
stuff
stuff
stuff
```

Comment: `</br>` doesn't exist.

Comment: So you're making a list called `list`, and putting that list _inside_ another list called `var`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: that's just html format for '\n' - new line

Comment: @khelwood to make sure his code will be un-debuggable

Comment: So I can add the contents of that list inside another function in the code

Comment: @E_C `<br />` is the html tag for `\n`

Comment: My focus is more on removing the "[]" and "'", but I can make adjustments to the <br /> :)

Comment: Would you please write the expected html code rather than the expected html display?

Comment: i'm coding in python and creating a new html file using htmlFile.write()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a requirement for it to be a one-liner?

If not:

```
list1 = ['stuff']
list2 = ['stuff']
list3 = ['stuff']

def itemList(itm):
    return [list1[itm], list2[itm], list3[itm]] 

listToWrite = itemList(0) 

for s in listToWrite:
    htmlFile.write('<li>{0}</li>'.format(s))
```

This will produce a HTML file looking like this:

```
<li>stuff</li>
<li>stuff</li>
<li>stuff</li>
```

So when you view the webpage, it'll be:

```
stuff
stuff
stuff
```

Edit: You were appending a list to the variable `var`, so `var` was a list of lists. There's no need for this, so instead just return the newly created list from your `itemList` function and iterate over it.

Comment: Web front-end isn't my thing: have removed `<br>` tag from the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that is really better :) I suggest you to use his variable rather than hardcoding the list

Comment: Thanks man, In gave it a go and still got the same result, but I appreciate the suggestion :)

Comment: @E_C The above code shouldn't write `['stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff']` to the HTML file, there's no way that could happen!

Comment: I changed it to:
for s in var:
        htmlFile.write('<li>{0}</li>'.format(s))

Comment: @E_C I've updated my answer to incorporate more of your code. You were appending the variable `list` to the variable `var` - I assume that was so that `list` had global scope. This isn't necessary - you can simply just return the list that you create within `itemList` and iterate over that.

Comment: My code is a bit more complex, I can't post it all up here because it's long and also I don't want other students to use it haha, but basically 'stuff" is a list of 10 items imported from a live website. Thanks for helping though

Comment: The principle is the same regardless of the length or content of the lists - this is likely the easiest way to accomplish what you're attempting to so I'd suggest staying on this path! Either way, good luck!

Comment: Thanks @AdamMitchell! I'll do it this way, instead of wasting more time :)